# Google map Background color for Map type GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps-utils

I have used Ground overlay of my floorplan added to Google Map. It loads up perfectly. Code is as shown below.

```
override fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = map;

    mMap.setOnGroundOverlayClickListener(this);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(DEFAULT_LAT_LNG, 1F));
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);


    mGroundOverlay = mMap.addGroundOverlay(GroundOverlayOptions()
            .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)).anchor(0F, 1F)
            .position(DEFAULT_LAT_LNG, floorPlanWidth.toFloat(), 
    floorPlanHeight.toFloat()));

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(mGroundOverlay.getBounds(), 0))
}
```

This shall produce the UI as attached below.

[image]

I have 2 questions here :

1. How do i change the background color to the color of my choice?
2. How do i Zoom In and Zoom Out programmatically? Say i want to zoom in by 5F as soon as map loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For p.1 easiest way is to use additional `GroundOverlay` which is solid color bitmap filled  by background color of your ground overlay. Exactly for your example picture can be something like that (`overlay_background.png`):

[image: Background overlay]

That picture you should use as "background" `GroundOverlay` placed under your "floors" `GroundOverlay`s.

To ensure that the "background" `GroundOverlay` covers the entire visible area you should scale that image slightly over the "floors" overlay. You can do it via [`.positionFromBounds()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlayOptions#positionFromBounds(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds)) method of `GroundOverlayOptions`. For get "background" overlay bounds `radius` distant from the `center` you can use method like that:

```
public LatLngBounds createBounds(LatLng center, float radius) {
    LatLngBounds bounds = null;
    if (center != null) {
        bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
                .include(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(center, radius * Math.sqrt(2), 45))
                .include(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(center, radius * Math.sqrt(2), 225))
                .build();
    }
    return bounds;
}
```

where `SphericalUtil` is part of [Maps SDK for Android Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility). How to add it for project described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/setup).

Also via [`setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/views#restricting_the_users_panning_to_a_given_area) method you can set camera view bounds slightly less then "background" overlay area to avoid situation when user scrolls map out of "background" overlay bounds. You need to set minimal and maximal zoom level (via [`setMinZoomPreference()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setMinZoomPreference(float)) and [`setMaxZoomPreference()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setMaxZoomPreference(float))) also.

So general idea is described on figure below:

[image: Idea description]

For placing "background" `GroundOverlay` under your "floors" `GroundOverlay`s you can use `.setZIndex()` method of [`GroundOverlayOptions`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlayOptions#getZIndex()) or [`GroundOverlay`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay#setZIndex(float)) and set Z-Index for "background" `GroundOverlay` less than Z-Index of "floors" `GroundOverlay` e.g. `Z-Index = 1` for "background" and `Z-Index = 2` for floor overlay (default value of Z-Index is `0`).

So with source code like this:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;

    // calculate borders for "background" overlay
    LatLngBounds borders = createBounds(OVERLAY_CENTER, 1000);

    // constrain the camera target to slightly less bounds.
    LatLngBounds cameraBorders = createBounds(OVERLAY_CENTER, 500);
    mGoogleMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(borders);
    mGoogleMap.setMinZoomPreference(18.0f);
    mGoogleMap.setMaxZoomPreference(21.0f);

    GroundOverlayOptions overlayBackground = new GroundOverlayOptions()
            .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.overlay_background))
            .transparency(0.0f)
            .bearing(0)
            .zIndex(1) // NB! set Z-Index for "background" overlay
            .positionFromBounds(borders);

    mGoogleMap.addGroundOverlay(overlayBackground);

    mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);

    GroundOverlayOptions overlayOptions = new GroundOverlayOptions()
            .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.overlay))
            .transparency(0.0f)
            .bearing(0)
            .zIndex(2)  // NB! set Z-Index for "floor" overlay
            .position(OVERLAY_CENTER, 200f);

    GroundOverlay overlay = mGoogleMap.addGroundOverlay(overlayOptions);

    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(OVERLAY_CENTER, 18.0f));
}
```

you can get result like that:

[image: Overlay background result]

For p.2 question IMHO easiest way is to "emulate" indoor maps by using set of floors overlay. In that case you can show necessary floor by adding corresponding floor overlay to map and show/hide it by using [`setTransparency()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay#setTransparency(float)) method: use `use setTransparency(1)` for all floors that you want to hide, and `setTransparency(0)` for one floor, for which needs to be shown. For example, for display an overlay for floor #3:

```
GroundOverlay floor1Overlay = mGoogleMap.addGroundOverlay(floor1OverlayOptions);
GroundOverlay floor2Overlay = mGoogleMap.addGroundOverlay(floor2OverlayOptions);
GroundOverlay floor3Overlay = mGoogleMap.addGroundOverlay(floor2OverlayOptions);
...
floor1Overlay.setTransparency(1);
floor2Overlay.setTransparency(1);
floor3Overlay.setTransparency(0);
```

Or you can remove not necessary floors overlay from map with [`remove()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay#remove()) method on `GroundOverlay` (not on `GroundOverlayOptions`!) object and recreate it when needed again. For this you need to store floor overlay object when it was added on map:

```
GroundOverlay floor1Overlay = mGoogleMap.addGroundOverlay(floor1OverlayOptions);
...
floor1Overlay.remove();
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation

Comment: I have another question which i am struggling for. Could you please take a look at it when possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62255292/android-pulse-ring-animation-effect-to-each-of-the-markers-added-in-google-map