# How to hide base map in google map android?

Tags: android, google-maps, openstreetmap

I want to hide the base map in google map v2
Because I added Tile Overlay from osmdroid to Google Map
This is my code:

```
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
    mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(19);
    String mUrl = "https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
    MyUrlTileProvider mTileProvider = new MyUrlTileProvider(256, 256, mUrl);
    mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(mTileProvider).zIndex(0));
```

But when zoom_in or zoom_out, it first loads the tile from Google Maps and then loads the tile from osm.
I want the base map of the show to be hidden and only the tiles to be loaded from osmdroid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to use [`GoogleMap.setMapType()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setMapType(int)) method and set map type to MAP_TYPE_NONE:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
    ...
}
```

But also you can create custom [`GroundOverlay`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay#setZIndex(float)) which is solid color bitmap filled by desired background color and place it exactly at current screen view (details you can find e.g [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62171094/6950238) answer), or even create custom [`MapView`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView)-based component and [override its `onDraw()`](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing) method and use [`Canvas`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas) object to fill it with solid color (e.g. white):

```
...
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
}
...
```

Comment: hi.thank's. Is there a better way to display OSMdroid in Google Maps?

Comment: @MehrdadLatifi Just use raw OSMdroid library, like in [this example](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library) without Google Maps at all if you need only OSMdroid. And, seems, you can accept the answer (set "checkbox" below answer rating).